# Determine if a child exists

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, removechild

I have an event driven flash program. I need to be able to call `removeChild()` if and only if an object is a child. `getChildByName()` and most other functions don't seem to allow for this and if you call `removeChild()` on an object that isn't a child it will throw an error. I suppose an option may be to catch the thrown error and just ignore it, but that seems like a bad solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid errors I normally just wrap `removeChild()` in `if(parent)`:

```
if(sprite.parent)
    sprite.parent.removeChild(sprite);
```

If the sprite doesn't have a parent, null will be given in the `if()` meaning `removeChild()` won't be called.

`removeChild()` is also run from the `parent` of the child (which we have already confirmed exists in the `if()` statement around it). This means the targeted parent is *always* the owner of the child.

---

`parent` is often forgotten but is an extremely powerful property for simplifying all `DisplayList` related operations.

Comment: You can also do: sprite.parent && sprite.parent.removeChild(sprite);

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have `obj` and its supposed parent `p`, and you want to remove `obj` from `p`, if and only if `obj` is actually a child of `p`.

```
if (obj.parent == p)
    p.removeChild(obj);
```

That's the proper way to do it.

If `p` could be `null`, then:

```
if (p && obj.parent == p)
    p.removeChild(obj);
```

If `obj` itself could be `null`, then:

```
if (obj && p && obj.parent == p)
    p.removeChild(obj);
```